# How to change specific column to rows without changing the other columns in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have dataframe like this:

```
  Date       ID     Age      Gender        Fruits
  1.1.19     1      50         F            Apple
  2.1.19     1      50         F            Mango
  2.1.19     1      50         F            Orange
  1.1.19     2      75         M            Grapes
  4.1.19     3      20         M            Apple
  4.1.19     3      20         M            Grapes
```

I want to convert the Fruit column into further columns which gives binary info yes/no for each person. 
Desired output would be like this. And the missing date should be NaN.

```
Date          ID     Age      Gender        Apple    Mango      Orange    Grapes 
1.1.19         1      50         F            1        0           0         0
1.1.19         2      75         M            0        0           0         1
2.1.19         1      50         F            0        1           1         0 
3.1.19         NaN    NaN        NaN          NaN     NaN        NaN       NaN
4.1.19         3      20         M            1        0           0         1
```

I was thinking to use groupby but i dont need any aggregation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['Fruits'], prefix='', prefix_sep='')
```

Update

```
pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['Fruits'], prefix='', prefix_sep='').groupby('Date').max()
```

Comment: still missing the entry for 3.1.19

Comment: `df.join(pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['Fruits'], prefix='', prefix_sep=''))`

Comment: Its partial correct because on 2.1.19 there are two fruits for id 1 but i need the, in 1 row. With your solution it added 1 row for each item.

Comment: i dont understand why this `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'Timestamp' and 'int'`